# CORS issue with ASP.net Identity

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am working on an angular.js project with one of my friends, and we are running into a specific CORS (cross origin request) issue. The server is a Microsoft ASP.NET restful API, and I am using angular.js with Node.js.

We enabled CORS on the server side, and are able to get responses for everything else, accept the user login, which we are using ASP.NET Identity with. We always get the same error which I will post bellow, as well as the POST from the Client side. So basically my question is, does any one have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lectioserver.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/accounts/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

```
function login(username, password) {
        var innerconfig = {
            url: baseUrl + "/api/v1/accounts/login",
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                grant_type: "password"
            },
            method: "POST",
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'text/json'
            }
        };
        return $http(innerconfig).then(onSuccess, requestFailed);
        function onSuccess(results) {
            if (results && results.data) {
                $rootScope.access_token = results.data.access_token;
                return results.data;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content-type in the headers, this might fix the issue

`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

Comment: Thanks, for the response. That didn't solve the problem though

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because app that provides you token starts before CORS initiates.
Fixing it is very easy. You just need to go to `IdentityConfig.cs` and inside that there is function called as

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create
  (IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
```

Insert this following line of code there

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

This will enable CORS for Token request.
But problem is when we do this other normal requests will start throwing error since we have granted access origin * twice. Once in identiy and other in cors.
if you run into this error use this if statement on cors code in identity config you just pasted.

```
if(context.Request.ContentType == "text/plain")
```